# Can't get has_many & belongs_to in same model to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

It has been a while since I asked something around here.
Since I have just started playing around with Ruby, and can't get my head around this, I decided to come back here for some guidance.

I've read quite a few examples now, but I don't find a proper path to walk to solve this problem.

The idea is the following :

You have :

- A family
- A person

Their relationship is the following :

- There is one person that is the 'head' of the family
- Every person is part of a family (be it with multiple persons or just himself in it)

Now the current validation probably makes it impossible to perform this, but the idea is that there is no such thing as a family without a head, and no person without a family.
I've tried to express it the following way :

> Family class

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :head_id, presence: true

  belongs_to :head, :class_name => Person, foreign_key: 'head_id'
  has_many :persons
end
```

> Person class

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :family_id, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true

  belongs_to :family
end
```

Would any soul be so kind to offer me some advice?

The migration has a family_id on the Person-class side, the family consists of an extra column being person_id.

> Family migration

```
class CreateFamilies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :families do |t|
      t.integer :head_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

> Person migration

```
class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.integer :age
      t.integer :family_id

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got a circular dependency here. You cannot create families nor people.
Circular dependency usually indicates that there's a third element missing. 
[More eloquently and not completely related](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/08/01/circular-dependency-in-constructors-and-dependency-injection/) .

There are two kind of membership, head and non-head. Once your make them obvious in your code the circular dependency will be solved.

There a few solutions but you need to find the one fits you the best. This is mine.

Create a membership join table

```
class Family
  validates :memberships, presence: true, on: :update
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :people, through: :membership

  after_create :create_head_membership

  private

  def create_head_membership
    memberships.create role: 'head' # to be filled later
  end
end

class Membership
  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_many :memberships
  has_one :family, through: :membership # has_many, amrite?
  validates :memberships, presence: true, on: :update
end
```

The most important thing is avoid Person/Family direct manipulation, rather create something to handle this process and wrap it in a transaction

```
class God
  def make_family head_attrs
    fam, head = nil
    Family.transaction do
      fam = Family.create!
      head = Person.create! head_attrs
      fam.memberships.first.update_attribute! :person_id, head.id
    end

    fam
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand. However I was attempting to avoid this, as conceptually it felt ok to define it like this.

Comment: Also, I'm interested in the other possible solutions. Do you have a resource ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I properly understand your code, but please tell me what is a Publisher class? I think you should do it in this way:

Family model: 
has_many :persons
has_one :head, :class_name => Person, foreign_key: 'head_id'
validates :head_id, presence: true

Person model:
belongs_to :family
validates :family_id, presence: true
validates :first_name, presence: true

Family **has many** persons and **has one** head. The person **belongs to** family and it doesn't matter for the person if it's the head of family or not.

Other things like migrations and validations still the same.

Comment: It doesn't matter if that person is the head of the family or not, that is true.
However, it must remain true that every person is part of a family, no matter if he's the only member or not.  :)

If I'd change the belongs_to :head to has_one, that'd change the location of the key, and thus I'd have to change the migrations as well, shouldn't I ?

Answer (score 0):

Is better validate presence of :head that not head_id

```
class Family < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :head, presence: true

  belongs_to :head, :class_name => Person, foreign_key: 'head_id'

  has_many :persons
end
```

Person have two relations with Family, one if is head and another if is part of a family, you have to validate (as I put in the example) how you can handle this relationships.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :family, presence: true
  validates :first_name, presence: true

  belongs_to :family
  belongs_to :head, :class_name => 'Family', :foreign_key => 'head_id'
  validate :family_id_is_equal_to_head_id

  def family_id_is_equal_to_head_id 
      self.family = self.head
  end
end
```

Finally migrations are wrong, must define the relantionship

```
class CreateFamilies < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :families do |t|
      t.integer :head_id


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end

class CreatePersons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :persons do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.integer :age
      t.belongs_to :family
      t.integer :head_family_id


      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```